# Each element of affine open cover of a curve each of which containing the singular points meets every irreducible component?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, proof of Theorem 15.18 and stuck at understanding some statement.

My first main question is as follows :

**Q.** Let $C$ be a connected and non-empty noetherian space (possibly of pure dimension $1$ ; i.e., all irreducible component is of dimension $1$  ) with finitely many irreducible components $C_1, \dots, C_n$. Let $S \subseteq C$ be a finite subset whose points lie on more than one irreducible component of $C$. Then for each $1\le j \le n$, $S \cap C_j \neq \varnothing$ ?

This question originates from the following proof of the Theorem 15.18 of the Gortz's book :

> Theorem 15.18. Let $k$ be a field, and let $C$ be a separtaed curve over $k$. Then $C$ is quasi-projective over $k$.

At this point, we will prove the theorem under the additional assumption that $C$ is generically reduced so that $\operatorname{Sing}C$ is finite ( c.f. his book Remark 15.15-(4) ).

*Proof.* We may assume that $C$ is connected ( Remark 8.21 ).
(i) We first prove the theorem under the following assumption:

*The curve $C$ has an open affine covering $C= \cup_{i\in I} U_i$ such that every $U_i$ contains the finite set $\operatorname{Sing}C$ of non-normal points of $C$.*

We may assume that the index set $I$ is finite and that each $U_i \neq \varnothing$. Then **$U_i$ meets every irreducible component of $C$** because among the singular pints are in particular those point which lie on more than one irreducible component. Thus $U_i$ is open and dense in $C$ and .. (Omitted). QED.

Why the bold statement is true? There, 'curve $C$ over a field $k$' means a non-empty $k$-scheme of finite type satisfying following equivalent conditions :

(i) For every closed point $x\in C$, $\operatorname{dim}\mathcal{O}_{C,x} =1$.

(ii) The closed irreducible subsets of $C$ are the $C_i$  ( $C_1, \dots C_n$ are the irreducible components ) and the closed points of $C$. And none of the $C_i$ consists of only one point.

(iii) The scheme $C$ is of pure dimension $1$ ( i.e., $\operatorname{dim}C_i =1$ for all $i$ ).

( **Q.** Interlude question : as the statement followed by the underlined statement, why the singular points are in particular those points which lie on more than one irreducible component )

If our question is true, then since $\operatorname{Sing}C$ meets every irreducible component of $C$ and each $U_i$ contains $\operatorname{Sing}C$, each $U_i$ meets every irreducible component of $C$. And is our question true? Why?

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me say a few things / address different issues.

> ( Q. Interlude question : as the statement followed by the underlined statement, why the singular points are in particular those points which lie on more than one irreducible component )

A. It is not true that singular points are points that lie on more than one irreducible components e.g. take the nodal cubic. It *is* true that if a point lies on two components then it is a singular point. Think of it this way, the suppose $x$ is on two irreducible components. Then the local ring $O_x$ at that point is going to have zero divisors. This means it cannot be an integral domain and therefore certainly not a regular local ring (see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4331703/regular-local-rings-of-krull-dimension-1-are-integral-domains).)

> If our question is true, then since Sing meets every irreducible component of  and each  contains Sing, each  meets every irreducible component of . And is our question true? Why?

A. It is not true $Sing C$ meets each irreducible component. What is true that each $U_i$ will contain $Sing C$. So each $U_i$ will meet every irreducible component in at least one point due to connectedness.

Comment: Thanks. For the first interlude question, I got it. For the second question, perhaps, for every irreducible component $C_j$, is there another irreducible component $C_k$ such that $C_j \cap C_k \neq \varnothing$? If so, then a point in the intersecition is singular. So $U_i$ meets $C_j$ since $U_i \supseteq \operatorname{Sing}C$. And how can we show that, by using connectedness of $C$? Every irreducible component meets each other in connected space?

Comment: Perhaps, if we use : "disjoint union of non-empty closed sets is not connected" ? :)