# Understanding proof of Theorem 15.18 of Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book ( quasi-projectivity of separated curve )

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Theorem 15.18 (p.493) and stuck at understanding some statement.

Here the **curve $C$ over a field $k$** means that non-empty noetherian scheme of pure dimension $1$ (equivalently, the closed irreduicble subsets of $C$ are the $C_i$ (irreduicble components) and the closed points of $C$, and none of $C_i$ consists of only one point), and of finite type over $k$.

Theorem 15.18 and its proof is as follows :

> Theorem 15.18. Let $k$ be a field, and let $C$ be a separtaed curve over $k$. Then $C$ is quasi-projective over $k$.

At this point, we will prove the theorem under the additional assumption that $C$ is generically reduced so that $\operatorname{Sing}C$ is finite ( c.f. his book Remark 15.15-(4) ).

*Proof.* We may assume that $C$ is connected ( Remark 8.21 ).

(i) We first prove the theorem under the following assumption:

"The curve $C$ has an open affine covering $C= \cup_{i\in I} U_i$ such that every $U_i$ contains the finite set $\operatorname{Sing}C$ of non-normal points of $C$."

We may assume that the index set $I$ is finite and that each $U_i \neq \varnothing$. Then $U_i$ meets every irreducible component of $C$ because among the singular pints are in particular those point which lie on more than one irreducible component (c.f. [Each element of affine open cover of a curve each of which containing the singular points meets every irreducible component?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4670689/each-element-of-affine-open-cover-of-a-curve-each-of-which-containing-the-singul/4673662#4673662) ). Thus $U_i$ is open and dense in $C$ and the complement consists of finitely many closed points ( I could prove this by using the proof of the Corollary 15.3 in his book. If needed, I upload my own proof. Anyway, for now, we accept this statement.), all of whose local rings are normal. As $U_i$ is affine and of finite type over $k$, it admits an immersion into some affine space and hense also an immersion $g_i : U_i \to \mathbb{P}_k^{n_i}$ ( c.f. his book, p.87 above ). **By Proposition 15.5, we can extend $g_i$ to a morphism $\bar{g_i} : C \to \mathbb{P}_k^{n_i}$** which is separated because $C$ is separated. .. (Omitted ) QED.

Here the Proposition 15.5 is,

> Proposition 15.5. Let $S$ be a scheme, let $X$ be a normal noetherian $S$-scheme of dimension $1$, and let $Y$ be a proper $S$-scheme. Then every rational $S$-map $X-\!\! \rightarrow Y$ extends to a morphism $X\to Y$.

**Q.** **Why the bold statement in the proof is true?** Since $C$ may not be normal ( by the existence of possibly non-empty $\operatorname{Sing}C$ ), we can't apply the Proposition 15.5 directly to our situation. Through communication with the author (Gortz), he gave me a hint as follows :

"Here one should not apply Proposition 15.5 directly, but to a normal open
neighborhood of one of the points of $C\setminus U_i$. Because projective space
is separated, it is then clear the the resulting morphism in fact extends $g_i$."

I don't know how can we embody this hint into concrete proof. As a normal neighborhood of one of points of $C\setminus U_i$, what did he mean? How can we construct an extension of $g_i$ through some algorithm? Is there any other route to show the extendibility?

Can anyone help?